# PHP Curl obtain values of __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION from aspx page

Tags: php, asp.net, html, curl

Hi I have written the following script to login into a website. What I want to now do is perform a search on the page that we see after we login. Currently my script returns the page after you login. It has a form that has a search field and a button. I have also noticed that it uses __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION as part of its form. I am aware that the values for these two fields are not always going to be the same. So I wanted to know how I can retrieve these values from the form when I perform a search so that I can use them to post the form in my script. Here is the code I used to login:

```
    <?php

$post_data['ctl00$MainContent$EmailText'] = 'xxxx@xxxx.com';
$post_data['ctl00$MainContent$PasswordText'] = 'xxxx';
$post_data['ctl00$MainContent$LogInButton'] = 'Log On';

foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

$curl_connection =
  curl_init('https://www.XXXX.co.uk/Login.aspx');
$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

curl_close($curl_connection);

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show a copy of the returned HTML with the source you are looking to parse out?

Comment: unfortunatley the HTML contains some confidential details so I cant show that. However the main part of the page contains a search box and a submit button. In the actual HTML form code it also has two more fields that I mentioned above. When I perform a test search using LiveHTTP headers, those two fields as well as the search box value and button get sent. The values of the two fields are given when I first login and get to the page (saw this with LiveHTTP headers)

Answer (score 1):

You best bet would probably be to use PHP's DOMDocument class to traverse the returned HTML and get what you are looking for.  You could load the result string into DOMDocument then use `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementById` to get the nodes. The latter would be preferred if the input elements have id values.

Implementation would look something like:

```
// $result is string returned by cURL from your code
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);
$node = $dom->getElementById('your_element_id');
$node_value = $node->getAttribute('value');
```

Comment: To see if it works and gets the correct value, how can I print it out instead of showing the page?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins Like you would any variable I suppose - `var_dump($node, $node_value);`